# SQL - Issue with Having and Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping, aggregate, having

Hi I'm having an issue with a query that was once working.  My SQL skills aren't all that great, not sure what I'm missing.  Or if this is the correct approach.  Maybe use a temp table instead?

The basic gist is given a certain time frame,  I need to calculate the highest aggregate of points over 5 classes.

trialScores - keeps scores/points, 
trials, dog, people and member tables are just meta data

classId 5 requires a different date range

Here is my Query on MySQL

```
select
    t.id,
    d.id,
    p.id,
    p.firstname,
    p.lastname,
    d.id dogId,
    d.dogName,
    c.id,
    c.class,
    t.trialStartDate,
    s.points,
    if(c.id = 5, '2012-08-01', '2012-11-18') as startDate,
    if(c.id = 5, '2013-07-31', '2013-12-31') as endDate,
    SUM(ts.points) AS pointsAggregate
from trialScores ts
    inner join trials t on t.id = ts.trialId
    inner join dogs d on d.id = ts.dogId
    inner join people p on p.id = ts.personId
    inner join classes c on c.id = ts.classId
where t.deletedAt is null
    and ts.deletedAt is null
    and ts.memberAtTrial = 1
    and d.omitFromTripleCrownDOY = 0
    and t.associationId = 1           
GROUP BY p.id, ts.dogId, ts.classId
having t.trialStartDate between startDate and endDate
order by ts.classId, pointsAggregate desc
```

Looks like this fixed it, too much in the select and not in Group by?:

```
 select
d.dogName,
c.class,
p.firstName,
p.lastName,    
SUM(ts.points) AS pointsAggregate
from trialScores ts
inner join trials t on t.id = ts.trialId
inner join dogs d on d.id = ts.dogId
inner join people p on p.id = ts.personId
inner join classes c on c.id = ts.classId
where t.deletedAt is null
and ts.deletedAt is null
and ts.memberAtTrial = 1
and d.omitFromTripleCrownDOY = 0
and t.associationId = 1 
and t.trialStartDate between if(c.id = 5, '2012-08-01', '2012-11-18') and if(c.id = 5, '2013-07-31', '2013-12-31')  
GROUP BY ts.dogId, ts.classId
order by ts.classId, pointsAggregate desc
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the query are getting any error ? or you are not getting the expected result ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Sorry, no errors.. bad results.  If I manually look up the data and compare it is way off, some people are even omitted from the results that I know should be there.  Let me see if I can set up a sqlfiddle, may take a moment

Comment: Too much data to add but if John had 2 trialScores of 3 and 4 and Sue and trialScores of 5 and 6 for classId 1.  And Bill had trialScores of 0 and 15 and Mary had trialScores of 5 and 5 for class 2.  I'd want the out put to be: CLASS 1 - Sue 11, John 7 - CLASS 2 - Bill 15, Mary 10 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below query and let if it's work or not ?

```
select
d.dogName,
c.class,
p.firstName,
p.lastName,    
SUM(ts.points) AS pointsAggregate
from trialScores ts
inner join trials t on t.id = ts.trialId
inner join dogs d on d.id = ts.dogId
inner join people p on p.id = ts.personId
inner join classes c on c.id = ts.classId
where t.deletedAt is null
and ts.deletedAt is null
and ts.memberAtTrial = 1
and d.omitFromTripleCrownDOY = 0
and t.associationId = 1 
and t.trialStartDate between if(c.id = 5, '2012-08-01', '2012-11-18') and if(c.id = 5, '2013-07-31', '2013-12-31')  
GROUP BY ts.classId,p.firstName,p.lastName 
order by ts.classId, pointsAggregate desc
```

Comment: ok what happens there is it gives me the top per class.  So I get 5 resutls, one per class with the top points aggregate.  And the aggregate/people are way off.